# explode tables in sql

Tags: sql

Problem statement:

I have Product_id and Quantity column in my table
Say product_id A has 2 units, B has 3 units etc

How do i make a table with 2 rows of Product_id A, 3 rows of Product_id B?

Comment: You need to tag the sql environment you are using in your question otherwise it might not be answerable.

Comment: Use [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)

Comment: And you need to show some effort too. Post the SQL you have written so far to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did this exercise based on a recursive Common Table Expression:

```
;WITH CTE (Vals) 
AS (
SELECT 1 
 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 + Vals
FROM CTE WHERE Vals< 99
   )
SELECT Product_id
FROM       Mytable A 
INNER JOIN CTE C   ON C.Vals <= A.Quantity
ORDER BY A.Product_id
```

supposing Quantity < 99

could help you

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, tested on your example :

```
WITH tally(n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM tally WHERE n<100) 

SELECT Product_id, 1 as Quantity 
FROM MyTable CROSS JOIN tally 
WHERE n<=quantity 
ORDER BY Product_id;
```